# How to Use = to convert one type of Object or struct to the type necessary

Tags: swift

I neeed to asign one object to another with the operator = without as. Is there any way to do it? This is and example but I need it to do it for any class to other. Is there any func to redefine?

```
var a : NSNumber
var b = "1"
a = b
```

I'm using coredata, the function setValue(value: Any?, forkey: String) to import data in a file to an CoreData Object. And Crash when property is a Bool.

I don't want to use the operator as, and I try to redefine the operator = but it is not possible, also try to do init but doesn't work.

Comment: Why would this be necessary?

Comment: This is not possible even with `as`. You can only assign values with the same type (or in case of classes a subclass to its base class).

Comment: Unless this is just out of curiosity, I _guarantee_ this is an https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

Coredata uses bool values as NSNumber. so you need to convert it first.

let booleanNumber = NSNumber(value: booleanValue)
And then you can use that booleanNumber in setValue(value: Any?, forKey: String)

Answer (score 0):

> I neeed to asign one object to another with the operator = without as.

Swift is a strongly typed language, which means that you can't just assign a value of one type to a variable that's declared to have some other type. Instead, you need to actively convert the value to the desired type. How to do that will depend on the types in question; many types offer initializers that take common types, but you might end up having to write code to do the conversion if none exists already.

> ```
> var a : NSNumber
> var b = "1"
> a = b
> ```

In your example, `a` has type `NSNumber`, and `b`'s type is inferred from the `String` value that you're using to initialize it. You can't assign a `String` value to a `NSNumber` variable directly, so you'll need to convert. There are a few ways to do that; here's one:

```
a = NSNumber(int: Int(b) ?? 0)
```

That is, use `Int`'s `init?(String)` initializer to create an `Int` from the `String`. Since that produces an optional, you can use the nil coalescing operator (`??`) to ensure that there's some valid value in case the initializer fails (e.g. your string `b` doesn't contain something that can be recognized as an integer).

You'll need to do something similar to convert between any two types: look for existing initializers or other functions that can do the conversion, or write your own if none exists.